# Get Offline Messages From XMPP Without Becoming Online

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

We are using ejabberd server for our mobile chat application.
And we are using IOS XMPP-Framework for our IOS application ( https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

But we have a problem on implementation that we couldn't find a solution.
We've implemented every aspect of XMPP messaging and all works good besides one thing:

While our application is on background, our ejabberd server sends us push notifications to inform us about offline messages. (Only sends notification for offline messages)

Then we've decided to implement the IOS background push notification functionality to get offline messages while the application is on background.

But the problem is we have to become online(send presence) in order to get offline messages. 
But when we do that it creates 2 unwanted consequences:

1. The party who sends the message saw our presence as Online (Even though we are in the background)
2. Just because we are becoming online while the application is on background , our server cannot send push notification for other people's messages becuase we are online and server can only send notification for offline messages.

For solving that problem, only thing that I can think of is, if there is a way to retrieve offline messages from xmpp server without becoming online.
Does anyone know if Is there any way to do that with XMPP-Framework for ios

**[EDIT]
Let me clarify the issue a little bit more:**

Problems are more than just one:

Problem 1 -  Push notification problem:

```
1.1 - Server check if the message is sending to an online or offline user. If the user is offline server sends push notification to inform user but if the user is online server doesnt send anything. 
1.2 - When the application is in background and receive notification for offline messages, application become alive(still in background) and become online in order to get offline messages
1.3 - Because the client became online, server doesnt send the push notifications anymore but the application is still in background so the user cannot be informed about the message he/she received.
```

So In order to fix those problem I need to find a way to receive offline messages by not sending the online presence to server

Problem 2 - Message Receive Problem

```
2.1 - Server check if the message is sending to an online or offline user. If the user is offline server sends push notification to inform user but if the user is online server doesnt send anything. 
2.2 - When the application is in background and receive notification for offline messages, application become alive(still in background) and become online in order to get offline messages
2.3 - When the application became online server sends all offline messages to client but doesnt send the total count of offline messages(At least I cannot get it with IOS XMPPFramework)
2.4 - So I dont know how much longer the client should stay alive in the background because I dont know the total count of offline messages, so after getting 2-3 messages I have to suspend the application in the background. But in that case there might be buggy situations such as XMPP Framework receive the offline message but I suspend the client application before writing it to database etc...
```

In order to find a solution to those problems:

1. I need to find a way to get only 1 offline message when I want from server
2. If possible  I also need to get those offline messages without becoming online

Comment: any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [ejabberd_mod_offline_post](https://github.com/diamondbybold/ejabberd_mod_offline_post)

1. First config the Room must be a Member-Only room, and add all users as members right after you created it, so that be able to get a total.
2. Add above module into ejabberd modules.
3. Implement a Callback Service to handle the callback post.

The idea is when User go offline:

- In one-to-one case, offline_message_hook will be raised
- In MUC case, muc_filter_message will be raised, and any one not Presence-Available is offline.

[Edited]:

I was using it on 16.06.  And there was an error in the source code at lines:

```
...

Body = xml:get_path_s(Stanza, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]),

...

 Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s(list_to_binary("type"), Packet),

 Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]),

...
```

I fixed them by adding `f` to `xml:`, e.g.
Body = **f**xml:get_path_s(Stanza, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]),

And for MUC, the offline users is in the 'Offline' field as this format, 'user1..user2..user3..', what you need to do it to split them out from the string.

Comment: I'm already using mod_offline_post module (mod_interact) however I didnt understand what you actually mean. After I create a groupchat room I invite the users to newly created group but other than that I dont know how to add them as members(Can you send me a link about that?).  Also I dont know what do you mean by add above model into ejabberd models and implement a callback service. Can you be more specific about it .
Thanks

Comment: The mod_interact only support one-to-one offline message. Since you've used it, you know how it works.  This one I posted support MUC as well. Instead of inviting users to join, you add the users directly into the member list. http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#modifymember

Comment: Is it working with latest ejabberd 16.08 version. Because I've tried to use mod_offline_post instead but even if I succesfully configure it, it doesnt work(doesnt forward messages)

Comment: Actually I used them on 16.06, (16.08 had bug when installing on windows).  And there was an error when using mod_offline_post, see my Edited for the fix.  You can check it there was error in your logs.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now the problem is mod_offline_post forward the message to our webserver with To: part of the message seems like groupchat username like To:mygroup@mydomain.com but I need the specific offline receipant so I'll find the device tokens to send push notifications for specific receipant. Is something like that possible.
Example: **To:offlineuser1@mydomain.com** not **To:mygroup@mydomain.com**
I think we can do it(as much as I can see from code) but I dont know erlang , so I dont how to do it

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi check my edited, the users is in the 'Offline' filed.

Comment: I've one more question , is there any possibility to get the group chat room's name within the muc_filter_message method?  So I can pass the group name to our backend server
Thanks

Comment: Sorry myself don't know Erlang.  But from the source code, there is `"to=", RoomJID#jid.luser, Sep,`.  This looks like the RoomName to me, please try.  Since in groupchat, roomJid is as 'roomName@chatServer/userNickname'.

Comment: No its only showing the username of the group like: **roomJid@mydomain.com**  , what I need is the name of the room which can be fetched from configuration of the room. May be it can be in the MUCState or Stanza data but I dont know what is inside them. And I dont know any class reference documentation about those classes

Comment: Sorry can't help you, I guess you need to implement it in the module by yourself.

Comment: Ok Thanks, by the way i found out that this answer is in the wrong thread , its the answer of my  another question (
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522642/groupchat-push-notification-on-xmpp )

Comment: Actually I did copy it on purpose, it answers both.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a custom Extension Element to your "background" online presence, for example

```
<presence ...>
<source xmlns:="com.foo#background"/>
</presence>
```

then, client side, when you receive the presence, do not notify if the Extension Element "`source`" with xmlns "`com.foo#background`" exists.

Comment: Actually it doesnt matter to add an extension element , because the clients doesnt send the notification. Server side check if the message is an offline message it automatically sends the notification to device and when the IOS receive the notification it automaticly shows it on the device. So I need to find a solution to get offline messages without becoming online or find a way to get only 1 offline message(not getting all of them)

Comment: I didn't get the point, sorry. Issue it's about "other people se me online even if I'm on background" or something else? By last comment it seems you receive too much "offline" messages and you don't want to get more than one. So simply remove listener to the groupchat/chat after first one in offline mode it's recived, or implement a "waiting mode"  (true | false) that stores messages but displays just first one. It enables itself while first time in background, disable display after first received and enable queue, then when tap sends alle the received messages to your GUI object

Comment: I've edited my question, because comment part doesnt hold that much string

Comment: Ok, I have to think about it. I'd suggest to read: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#modoffline and official specs http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html