# In background connect Room using XMPP Framework in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework, node-xmpp

I am making chat application using XMPP Framework.For Group chat Room created successfully and also done chat successfully but for group notification i have not connect Group in Background.

i tried to group connect in background after XMPP authentication done but its not working properly because in background group connect process continues working so any person send invitation for join new group(Room)then its not receive.

so any one have idea for connect group in background then please help me because i have spent many hours but not found any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522642/groupchat-push-notification-on-xmpp/40558404#40558404

Comment: thank you for giving me reply i will try this solution.