# iOS XMPP cannot get message when app is closed

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on iOS app for chatting.
I made xmpp client with XMPP Framework.
But it is not working when closed app.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I want to show message notification when background or closed app like android.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522642/groupchat-push-notification-on-xmpp/40558404#40558404.  This one is for Ejabberd server.  You need to find similar if you are using other server.

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone devices, iOS will kill your app after it is in the background, although you can ask the system for up to 10 minutes more time after the user has backgrounded the app. Android apps do not have to worry about this on most devices. However some devices, such as Huawei and Xiaomi phones, will also kill you app after a certain period of inactivity in order to save battery life, unless the user specifies in settings that they don't want the system to kill the app.

There are two options. One option is to implement VOIP or GPS location tracking in your app; this way, it will be necessary for your app to run in the background, and thus iOS won't kill your app (though you will need to have a reasonable use-case for needing VOIP or GPS location tracking, otherwise your app won't get approved on the app store).

The other option is to let iOS kill your app, and then set up push notifications on your server, so that when a user receives a message while they are offline, you can send a message to APNS, telling them to send a push notification to the user's phone. Push notifications will need to be set up on both the client and server side.