# Ejabberd Push Notification Configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm implenting the ejabberd push notification functionality on my iOS client side using `XMPPFramework`.

I've watched the `process one`'s XMPP Academy [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LToKLTf-N_E&feature=youtu.be&t=22m34s), and tried to find some information about it on the web, But I couldn't find any solution for configuring the ejabberd to use Apple push notifications.

I couldn't figure out things like:

1. Where I need to put my apns certificates
2. How to edit ejabberd's configuration file to use these certificates

etc...

Where can I find detailed explanation for configuring ejabberd for apple push notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ejabberd guys can update/configure you APNS certificate from there side OR you have to purchase higher package to get all access on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification feature of ProcessOne is not on the [Community Version](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/#getejabberd).

However you can achieve that via hooks, check this [link to my answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40558250/3543150)